# Change date display format of Bootstrap 3 datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/. I'm binding data from database to this field as below.

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" name="expense_date" value="${exp.expenseDate}" required="required">
```

**Script**

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format : 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
</script>
```

But date retrieved from database show in this field as `Wed Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2014`. I need to show it as `2014-06-18`.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well check out this plugin:

[jquery-dateformat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

I guess you can use it so simple

```
var d = $.format.date("Wed Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2014", "yyyy/MM/dd");
console.log(d);
```

view a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mhd_reza/K6mLM/) on jsfiddle!